# COUNT() together with the rest of the table's columns

Tags: mysql

What's the easiest way to select the number of rows found, together with other columns from the table? The only way I've found is to do a join with a sub-query, but I imagine it's more resource heavy than such a simple task should be...

The result I'm looking for is

```
SELECT lots_of_rows, count(*)
FROM table
with some magic, so it doesn't reduce everything in one row.

f1  f2  f3    rowcount
----------------------
a   b   c     3
a   c   e     3
a   r   g     3
```

Or something like that.

Comment: I don't understand your question. "together with other columns from the table?" part has no logic to me.

Comment: He wants to to a normal select, and a count(*), whilst still getting all the rows and a total count somewhere without using a subselect and a join.

Comment: @m0skit0: he means that this isn't working: select id, count(id) from mytable

Comment: You want all the results of `select * from table` but also the count of the rows in the same query? Most likely you're going about this the wrong way. If you're running the query through some other programming language, you can probably obtain the record count from the results object that your query returns. If you tell us what language you're programming in (PHP? ASP.NET? ColdFusion?) we could give you an example.

Comment: If I do a COUNT() on a table, it would only result in a column called "COUNT()". I want to get a table that contains the count value plus other values from other columns in the table. EDIT: Like the rest are saying, I want to perform something like    "SELECT ID, COUNT(ID)"    but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a subquery, the last row will hold all nulls and the total rowcount in field `rowcount`

```
SELECT lots_of_rows, count(*) as rowcount
FROM atable
GROUP BY atable.primary_key WITH ROLLUP
```

Another option might is:

```
SELECT lots_of_rows FROM atable;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as rowcount;
```

The second query will return instantly, because it just gives you the rowcount from the first query.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: In that case you'll have to do `select found_rows()` in a separate select after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using an inline view, which will work even if your table doesn't have a primary key. By using an inline view, you don't have to use a join.

Note: This was done on Oracle, but I believe the SQL should work for MySQL or require minimal tweaking.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 CHAR(1), f2 CHAR(1), f3 CHAR(3));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('a','b','c');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('a','c','e');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('a','r','g');

SELECT a.f1
     , a.f2
     , a.f3
     , b.cnt
  FROM t1 a
     , (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt from t1) b
```

Result:

```
    F1  F2  F3  CNT
1   a   b   c   3
2   a   c   e   3
3   a   r   g   3
```